# use string content as variable - python

Tags: python

I am using a package that has operations inside the class (? not sure what either is really), and normally the data is called this way `data[package.operation]`. Since I have to do multiple operations thought of shortening it and do the following

```
list =["o1", "o2", "o3", "o4", "o5", "o6"]
for i in list:
     print data[package.i]
```

but since it's considering `i` as a string it doesnt do the operation, and if I take away the string then it is an undefined variable. Is there a way to go around this? Or will I just have to write it the long way?.

In particular I am using `pymatgen`, its package `Orbital` and with the `.operation` I want to call specific suborbitals. A real example of how it  would be used is `data[0][Orbital.s]`, the first [0] denotes the element in question for which to get the orbitals `s` (that's why I omitted it in the code above).

Comment: store the operations as the object not as a string. then i will be the object instead of a string.

Comment: Use `getattr(package, i)`. With `getattr` you can retrieve attributes of objects via their names as strings.

Comment: you mean take away the string? I did, and since they are not defined it returns the "variable is not defined" error

Comment: @M.O. `list = [package.o1, package.o2, package.o3]`

Comment: `getattr` worked wondefully! Thanks!

Comment: every time I see a question asking how to "use string content as variable" .... the answer is *always* "don't do that... use a dictionary"

Comment: @a_guest Can you post your comment as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @alex Done that, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) in order to dynamically select attributes from objects (the `Orbital` package in your case; for example `getattr(Orbital, 's')`).

So your loop would be rewritten to:

```
for op in ['o1', 'o2', 'o3', 'o4', 'o5', 'o6']:
    print(data[getattr(package, op)])
```